# Extended DbSet does not initialize correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.1. What I want to do is extend `DbSet` and override Find to put a bit of my own logic before the actual `DbSet.Find()` call.

Something like this:

```
public class ExtendedDbSet<T> : DbSet<T> where T: class
{
    public override T Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        // do something here
        return base.Find(keyValues);
    }
}
```

But when I do this, and use the `ExtendedDbSet` like so:

```
public class SomeContext: DbContext
{
    public SomeContext(DbContextOptions<SomeContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedDbSet<SomeEntity> Entities{ get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
            .ToTable("SomeEntity")
            .HasKey("ID");
    }
}
```

When I go to access `SomeContext.Entities` it is null. There is some setup that is not getting called but I'm not sure what it is. If I just change `ExtendedDbSet<T>` to `DbSet<T>` `SomeContext.Entities` is initialized as I expect. I looked through the docs for some EF lifecycle hooks that I may use but didn't see many that looked like what I would need. I did try to override `DbContext.Set()` in my context but I didn't even see it being called.

Comment: Personally, I tend to avoid using `.Find()` anyway, always prefer to be explicit with a `.Where(...)`. However, perhaps if you explain what it is you're trying to do, we could suggest a better way of achieving that.

Comment: This kind of expands on what @DavidG says. If you look at the documentation for `DbSet<T>`, you may miss that it implements LINQ's [`IQueryable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=netcore-2.1) and [all the methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netcore-2.1) that interface supports. (Side note: Ignore the first argument in those method declarations, `IQueryable<T>`'s page on the new site doesn't list its extension methods and I had to link the static versions instead)

Comment: @DavidG - thanks for the response. What I was trying to do was give some implicit fault tolerance to `Find()` calls that extend the context. There is an existing codebase that uses `Find()` all the over the place and I wanted to introduce the resilience with minimum change to the existing codebase

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fault tolerance"?

Comment: @DavidG - retries on transient database errors, circuit breakers etc

Comment: Oh, in that case, use the built in stuff https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency